# mapbox-gl-js route is not accurate

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

[image: route image]

I'm new with map box and java scripts, i have try route mapping system but its not accurate. i don't know if routing map using map box-gl-js is normally its become like this or my code cause that problem. i follow the tutorial from https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/getting-started-directions-api/ .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the answer in another Stackoverflow question ([Does Mapbox Directions API limit the number or precision of coordinates in a response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58530748/does-mapbox-directions-api-limit-the-number-or-precision-of-coordinates-in-a-res)):

You can use the `overview=full` which is an optional parameter in your queries to get the most detailed geometry, so your queries would look something like this:

Query 1

https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-73.989%2C40.733%3B-74%2C40.733.json?access_token=my_access_token&geometries=geojson&overview=full

Query 2

https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/-73.989%2C40.733%3B-94%2C40.733.json?access_token=my_access_token&geometries=geojson&overview=full

If you put them in the API playground, you should see a more detailed route for your 2nd Query.